# How to increase the partition space for my local active drive... without formatting?

Tags: operating-systems, partitioning, filesystems

I want to increase my local disk drive i.e C: partiton space..

I dont want to format my drive and do partition...

Is there any way to avoid formatting.. and increase the partition space in C: ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an application like [Acronis Disc Director Suite](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/):

> A powerful and easy-to-use tool for managing disks and volumes. With a
>   comprehensive set of operations, you can organize your hard disk and
>   volume configuration for optimal performance, while keeping your data
>   safe.

or [Partition Magic](http://partition-magic.soft32.com/):

> Partition Magic is a computer program that allows you to slice your
>   hard drive up into several partitions. This allows one physical disc
>   drive to be used as if it were several drives. Once created, the
>   partitions can be re-sized without losing any of the data stored in
>   them.

Answer (score 0):

As [Partition Magic](http://us.norton.com/products/overview.jsp?pcid=sp&pvid=pm80) is no longer developed, you may be better off with [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start), which is also free.
This will allow you to re size the other partitions on your disk to make room for increasing the size of your C drive.
It also includes [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) so you can back up your drive before you re size anything